# Sieve of Eratosthenes Prime Number Program

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

For my lab I have been asked to write a program which prints off the prime numbers under 100 using the Sieve of Eratosthenes. However I have written the program and a number of non-prime numbers such as 27,33 and 99 are being printed out. Sorry for the poor explanation but here is my code, i hope someone can offer some advice or a solution. Thanks!

```
public class SOE {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        boolean [] myArray = new boolean[100];
        int j=0;

        for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) { //Initialises array
            myArray[i] = false;
        }

        for(int i=2;i<myArray.length;i++) { //loops through slot numbers
            while(j<myArray.length) { //loops through multiples
                if(j%i == 0 || j%5==0) {
                    myArray[j] = true;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) { //prints out prime numbers
            if(myArray[i]==false) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Eratosthenes", but I guess you came pretty close.

Comment: In the line marked "loops through multiples": where does `j` start when `i=2` in the `for` loop?  Where does `j` start the next time through the `for` loop, when `i=3`?

Comment: I changed j to equal to 2. So for the next line it would equal 3?

Comment: `j%5==0` why do you do that?

Comment: Are you saying you made a change to your code?  Does it work now?  If it doesn't, then my suggestion is: add `System.out.println(j);` just before the line that says "loops through multiples", and I think you will see what the problem is (or at least one problem).

Comment: you never reset j. it should be `for(int j=i+1;j<myArray.length;j++) {` instead of the while loop

Comment: Yes i changed the code there. I put that println statement in too and it's prints 2 once then it prints off 100 a number of times, kind of confused why

Comment: As a side note there's no need to initialize the array. Boolean array values default to false: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5

Comment: changed it to a for loop and it works now, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eratosthenes sieve is usually much simpler :

```
for(int i = 2; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i]) {continue;}
    j = 2 * i;
    while(j < myArray.length) {
        myArray[j] = true;
        j += i;
    }
}
```

That will eliminate in order `4, 6, 8, ...`, then `6, 9, ...`, then skip `4`, then `10,...`, then skip `6`... and so on

Comment: Ah I see, but what does the {continue;} mean?

Comment: it skips the already eliminated values (4, 6, 8, 9, ...) so that when you reach the j loop, i is always prime.